# How can I fix the range of a Google Sheet MATCH function when using a move rows apps script?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a [Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BKOxgZmAIoAzpmrF5NBChjFMXheyUEkf7SXVXCJs3zw/edit?usp=sharing) with a script to move rows at a set interval. The last row is moved to the top and all consecutive rows move down one, thus creating a loop. This sheet feeds a dynamic gallery of 10 stores which appear in consecutive blocks, managed by left and right arrows. Each block has a button which takes the value of the particular store of the block being viewed.

I want to register the row a store is on when this button is clicked so, in order to identify it, I have placed a MATCH function in a cell of each row with a formula like this: `=MATCH("Store 10",B2:B11,0)`. All's fine up to this point however, when the row moves, the range also shifts. For example, when Store 10 moves from the last row to the first, the above formula changes to  `=MATCH("Store 10",B3:B11,0)`. This obviously renders the  whole idea useless since Store 10, which now resides in the first row (B2), is not even found, since B2 is not included in the formula's range anymore!

Is there a fix to this or a better way to achieve my goal?

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you expect after moving the row. However, I give you a solution so that the formula remains as is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in G1

```
={"title of column";arrayformula(MATCH(offset(B1,1,,10),offset(B1,1,,10),0))}
```

Comment: Thank you, but it gives me the following error: 

Error
Array result was not expanded because it would overwrite data in G2.

Comment: Thank you! It seems to be working fine now. I'll have to look into the offset function to learn how it works.